# Merge [maps], [map], [map-ui] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I'm not sure if there is any meaningful difference between the questions tagged [maps](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps), [map](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map), or [map-ui](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map-ui).

Might we decide which is the canonical tag and merge the other two under that?

[map](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map) has the most questions and has an existing tag wiki, so in the event of a merge it seems like the best candidate as the parent tag.

Comment: We usually pluralize nouns so [maps] is probably best IMO

Comment: I'm all for sticking with conventions previously established

Comment: English Language and Usage Stack Exchange had a discussion on whether tags should be Plural or Singular. Consensus based on votes was Plural - http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/72/should-we-prefer-singular-or-plural-in-tags.

Comment: Plural makes sense to me because the tag is describing a collection of content, which is plural.  Some DBAs might disagree, as they commonly view a table (or in this case a tag) as a container and the label describes what is inside, not the quantity.  However in our case it is best to follow the convention the rest of the SE network uses as that is what the user is accustomed to and would expect to see.

Comment: @Charles, the "DBA view" is not applicable here. Generally, SE tags are topics, not categories: they describe the question's topic rather than the question itself. (There are a small number of exceptions, such as this question's 'discussion' tag.) For example, if a question is tagged 'foo' this does not mean the question _is_ a foo, it means the question is _about_ foo. A map question is not _actually_ a _map_, and it is not about _map_; it is about _maps_. Hence the tag should be `maps`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, let's merge them all into [maps](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps).

---

Done, the tags are all synonyms of [maps](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maps) now.